# Python: How to type a function which takes a union of possible class names as input

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, typing

Consider the following:

```py
class AbstractLanguageClass:
    @staticmethod
    def say_hello() -> None:
        raise Exception("Not implemented")


class French(AbstractLanguageClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def say_hello() -> None:
        print("Bonjour")


class English(AbstractLanguageClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def say_hello() -> None:
        print("Hello")


def hello_sayer(
    Language_Class: type,  # This type-hinting is what I'm unsure of
):
    Language_Class.say_hello()


hello_sayer(French)  # Correctly prints "Bonjour"
print(type(French))  # prints <class 'type'>
```

Running MyPy, I get the following error:

```
error: "type" has no attribute "say_hello"
```

What is the appropriate way to type-hint this use-case, where multiple classes implement a common static method, and we're not giving (as argument to some function) an instance of said classes, but rather the class name itself (to use their respective static methods) ?

PS: FYI, my real use-case is actually a generic caster function for a bunch of customized IntEnums, that have some common method mixins. This caster function can take a string, an int, or an enum instance; as well as such an IntEnum-derived class; then uses the class's from_str, deserialize, from_int, or constructor functions to cast, do nothing, or return an error. In the spirit of DRY code and type-safety, this is a very useful function to have in my case.

Comment: `AbstractLanguageClass`? Or maybe `Type[AbstractLanguageClass]`?

Comment: The type hint is surly `Type[AbstractLanguageClass]`, but it's not clear why `hello_sayer` is a function at all, rather than a method of `AbstractLanguageClass`. (Or why it exists at all, rather than using `methodcaller('say_hello')` as necessary.)

Comment: @chepner Thanks, `Type[AbstractLanguageClass]` indeed seems to work. What about in the case of multiple mixins ? Do I just make a "centralizing" mixin that's just there to inherit the others, and inherit from that single one rather than multiple others (then type as `Type[CentralizingMixi,]` ? Also: I didn't make `hello_sayer` a method of `AbstractLanguageClass` in my real use-case because I had to deal with some issues making sure the instance was indeed of "the most specific class" and not the parent, but I'll take a look again to see if I can do that, seems better. Thanks again in any case!

Comment: This might also be an artifact of a minimal example, but why do you have classes that have nothing but static methods?

Comment: Generally there's a static method (from_type_X) and a normal method (to_type_X) in these parent-class-mixins. I'll also have AbstractLanguageClass not be abstract and use a similar design pattern (and those times, thankfully rare, I might need to use __new__ appropriately). The reason why this complexity is necessary is because I'm building a binding over C with ctypes (with a bunch of complex resource management), and the complexity of ctypes definitely needs to be hidden from the end-user of the API. I had type-hinted most of my code for legibility, but have now started using MyPy as well.